# SQL71501 error building dacpac

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2015, dacpac

I have looked up various answers on here and none has helped me thus far.

I am rebuilding a database project and it is complaining about one particular script:

```
CREATE USER [doro] FOR LOGIN [doro];
```

Now there are other scripts under the security folder which are exactly the same with different logins - which it does not complain about.

With this particular user the error is:

```
SQL71501: User [doro] has an unresolved reference to Login [doro].
```

I tried following some suggestions and using the "Add New" option to add the login but this made several other errors appear in relation to that login.

I have the master database reference.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Also, does a rebuild sync the dacpac with the original source database or do you have to manually do a compare and update?

thanks,

KS

Comment: What are the other errors that appear when you add a script with "CREATE LOGIN [doro] WITH PASSWORD = 'password'"?

Comment: Also, the database project does not automatically update itself.  The expected workflow is to change the database project first, and then publish changes to the database and not the other way around. =^)